# How to run a command automatically on a terminal when I navigate to a particular folder?

Tags: linux, terminal, rvm

I open a terminal and navigate to my project folder (ex: `cd /proj/tickecting_app`). After this I execute this command `rvm use ruby 1.9.x@gemset`. Every time I open the terminal I want this command to run this. Is there a way to **run this automatically**? And to be more specific I navigate to **different projects in separate tabs**(ex: in first tab `cd /proj/tickecting_app` and run `rvm use ruby 1.9.x@gemset`, second tab `cd /proj/rss_feed_app` and run `rvm use ruby 2.1.x@gemset`). I want to run different commands depending upon the project. Is this possible?

Comment: I think this might get better and more enthusiastic response in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Create as file /usr/bin/rvm_inside_my_dirs.sh
chmod 755 /usr/bin/rvm_inside_my_dirs.sh

Content of file

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "You inside ${PWD}"
 case ${PWD}/ in
    /proj/tickecting_app*) rvm use ruby 1.9.x@gemset;;
     /proj/rss_feed_app*) rvm use ruby 2.1.x@gemset;;
    *) echo "away from dirs";;
 esac
```

Use

```
cd /proj/tickecting_app
rvm_inside_my_dirs.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in fact i was looking for a script which runs the rvm command when i navigate to the proj folder. That means i want to avoid typing this line also **rvm_inside_my_dirs.sh**

Comment: Since am using rvm i added .rvmrc file inside my proj folder and added the command inside that. Its working now.